# telnet-сервер.android

Tags: android, telnet

Возможно ли android-устройству открысть telnet-сервер ? Просто интересно..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Телнет сервер - это просто обычный tcp сервер. Его сделать реально. Поэтому мой ответ такой  - и сервер, и клиент сделать реально. Более того, их [куча](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=telnet&c=apps).